# How to append id attribute by child with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, attr

I have this markup:

```
<div>
  <span id="01">
</div>
<div>
  <span id="02">
</div>
```

i need to add some id for the `div` element by their span child, i try it with jquery but something is worng...

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).find('span').attr('id'));
})
```

Thx for help.

Comment: id should be unique in a document, so try `$(this).attr('id', 'parent-' + $(this).find('span').attr('id'));`

Comment: the id attribute should be unique, meaning you shouldn't have the same id on more than one element.
are you getting any console errors? you are missing a ";" at the end of the .each(), might cause it.

Also id cannot be a number, it has to start with a letter.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I checked on safari and actually works on chrome and nothing happens, but after some corretcs it's fine..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example seems to work fine. However id's should be unique, so I would suggest:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id', 'div-' + $(this).find('span').attr('id'));
});
```

I also assume you're running your example after page load event.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested your code in Safari 6. It works. I would like to say that setting the id identical to the ID of the span is not a good idea because IDs should be unique.

Also, what's not working for you?

I know this should probably be a comment but I can't comment yet (too low reputation)